# How to check if Set B has at least one element that is not in Set A

Tags: java, java-8, set

So I have two sets: A and B. I need to check if set B contains anything that is not in the set A. There are maybe intersections, so I cannot just check if set A contains set B.
I can obviously do this:

```
for (String string : setA) {
  if (!setB.contains(string) {
    break;
  }
}
```

or using the Guava library:

```
Sets.intersection(setA, setB).containsAll(setB); // returns false if there are elements outside.
```

But is there any way that would perform better or may be just cleaner or more elegant?
Thanks.

Comment: "cleaner" is opinion based. Java is never as pythonic as C++...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I changed my question to be less opinion based, thanks.

Comment: "Perform better". Trust me, that's not a performance hotspot.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-the-uncommon-elements-from-two-sets

Comment: `setA.stream().anyMatch(x -> ! setB.contains(x))`

Comment: @SahilManchanda This is not symmetric difference. It's obviously asymmetric as I need to check exactly one of the sets.

Comment: I'm not really seeing how this is different from `containsAll`. The [implementation in `AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29), for example, is identical to your first snippet.

Comment: @Radiodef looks like you are right and that suffices...

Comment: The title and body of question swap A and B. I am assuming you want to know if A contains something not in B. In that case first return true if A is larger than B; otherwise use Misha's code. This algorithm is O(min(|A|, |B|)) whereas the first snippet in the OP is O(|A|) and the other snippet in the OP and the answers are O(|A|+|B|).

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret: why should swapping the names `A` and `B` change the program logic in any way?

Comment: @Holger A name is just a name. But we must keep names consistent between usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“`B` *contains an element not in* `A`” is the exact opposite of “`A` *contains all elements of* `B`”, therefore, the already existing method `containsAll` is sufficient to answer that question.

```
if(!setA.containsAll(setB)) {
    System.out.println("setB contains an element not in setA");
}
```

You may shortcut using `setB.size()>setA.size() || !setA.containsAll(setB)`, but this requires that the sets agree on the definition of equality, e.g. if one set is a `SortedSet` using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` as comparator and the other is a `HashSet`, this won’t work (but the definition of the correct outcome is tricky with such combinations anyway).

If `setB` is really large, you might get a benefit from using a parallel stream like

```
if(!setB.parallelStream().allMatch(setA::contains)) {
    System.out.println("setB contains an element not in setA");
}
```

but this is rather rare.

Answer (score 3):

Merge all elements into another set and compare the total elements:

```
Set ab = new Set(a);
ab.addAll(b);

if (ab.size() != b.size()) break; // that means `a` had some element that was not in b
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use streams (parallel) and functional mix

```
setB.parallelStream().filter(((Predicate<String>)setA::contains).negate()).findFirst();
```

same as

```
setB.parallelStream().filter(bi -> { return !setA.contains(bi);}).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Straight Java

1. Duplicate the "target" set.
2. `duplicateSet.removeAll(otherSet)`
3. If duplicateSet is not empty, then the target contains one or more elements that are not in the "otherSet"

#### Apache SetUtils

1. `xyz = SetUtils.difference(seta, setb)`;
2. if xyz.size() > 0 then seta contains one or more elements that are not in setb.

Comment: `removeAll` and `addAll`, just the way around and still different :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try algorithm with removing elements from setB:

```
if (setB.size() > setA.size()) {
  return true;
}
for (String s : setA) {
  //boolean contains = setB.contains(s);
  boolean contains = setB.remove(s);
  if (contains) return true;
}
```